# Unable to access XML file from Virtual directory after editing the file

Tags: java, weblogic, virtual-directory

I am accessing an XML file through virtual directory and XML is kept at application server. Initially parsing was working fine but when I made some changes in XML after that I am not able to access that XML file. In that case I need to re-start the services then its working.

```
code : weblogic.xml

<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
        <wls:local-path>/app/upload_files/</wls:local-path>
        <wls:url-pattern>/Banner/*</wls:url-pattern>
        <wls:url-pattern>/Login/*</wls:url-pattern>
        <wls:url-pattern>/Home/*</wls:url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you you are using default value for resource-reload-check-secs (which is -1 in production mode and 1 in development mode). This parameter controls caching of resource metadata (like file size for static resources,  etc). -1 means that never reload the metadata so even if you change the static resource WLS will never reload the resource afresh.

And if this is the case for your XML file and if your XML file has changed in size, WLS would end up reading it partially if new file size is greater and XML parser would break, or give you an IO exception if new file size is lesser.

You can try re-delpoying the application.

Or if you frequently change the static resources then you may change value of resource-reload-check-secs to 0 or 1

sample weblogic.xml:

```
....
<container-descriptor>
<resource-reload-check-secs>0</resource-reload-check-secs>
</container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1067857

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input.If I make it 0 then the files doesnt cached or it will get cached whenever file size gets changed.pls add your comment on this..

Comment: If you notice the definition of "resource-reload-check-secs" in vendor documentation, there is catch about it - this parameter controls the caching of metadata and not the resource directly. If you  set it to -1 then WLS never reloads the metadata or in other words it is cached permanently (till JVM is running or application is redeployed). If we set it to 0, then metadata is always reloaded afresh and in other words this means caching of metadata is disabled. If we set it to 1, then WLS reloads the metadata every 1 second, and in other words metadata cache is renewed every 1 second.

Comment: If i write 60 over there that means cache will load in every 60 second.is it so?

Comment: Yes, cache should get refreshed after 60 seconds

Comment: @Abid In my tests, this will impact in other resources of the web application, like images that normally you want to cache.